# Deploying exploded war in Tomcat using Context appBase

Tags: java, tomcat

I am looking for an option to deploy exploded war in Tomcat using the context file in /var/tomcat/server/conf/Catalina/localost/myapp.xml

where myapp.xml is like

```
<Context appBase="/opt/dist/myapp/" debug="0" crossContext="true" />
```

But it is not loading the myapp application.

It works fine when I use docBase pointing to myapp.war

```
<Context docBase="/opt/dist/myapp.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" />
```

Does Tomcat support loading exploded war using Context/appBase?

Comment: as far as I know there is no appBase attribute in Tomcats Context element: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: try out to place the context under `{CATALINA}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/` folder and have another try

Comment: Not sure why I dindn't try this earlier, but using the webapp path in docBase property, tomcat loads my webapp                                                     <Context docBase="/opt/dist/myapp/" debug="0" crossContext="true" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine when I use exploded war (webapp) path in the docBase.